# Default Value Prometheus Label

Tags: prometheus

I want to set Default value for Prometheus Label, if Label is set by customer.

how should it Looks like in config file

```
- job_name: cadvisor   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have in my prometheus.yml.  Stuff after the '#' is a comment.  My job name has dashes instead of spaces.  Hope that helps.

```
---
global:
  scrape_interval: 60s
  evaluation_interval: 60s

scrape_configs:
  -
    job_name: 'My-Cluster-Label'  # My-Cluster-Label metrics
    scrape_interval: 60s
    metrics_path: /app/metrics
    static_configs:
      -
        targets: ['my_docker_host:19000',
                  'next_docker_host:19000',
                  'another_docker_host:19000']
```